# Welcome page not loading with JWT

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, extjs, jwt

I'm using Spring Boot with ExtJS with a /login page that is a plain JSP with some JQuery javascript.  I'm attempting to integrate JWT to secure my data apis. Using what I could find for implementing JWT, I have implemented a JWTRequestFilter and removed the built-in login flow from Spring Security.

My login form now makes an $ajax POST request to an /authenticate method that returns a token back in the response.  When I set the Authentication header in Postman manually and fire the GET request for the /welcome page, I get a valid response...

The following code is how I'm trying to update the headers with the token and GET the /welcome page.  I am getting 401 errors because the Authentication header is missing when I try to access the page with this code...

```
$form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({  
      url: $form.attr('action'), 
      type: 'POST', 
      dataType: 'json', 
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(dat), 
      success: function(result) {
  
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (3*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        
    //  $('head').append('<meta name="Authorization" content="Bearer ' + result.token + '"');
        window.localStorage.setItem("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.token);
    //    document.cookie = "Authorization=Bearer "+result.token + ";" + expires + ";path=/;httpOnly"; 
        window.location="/welcome";
}  error: funciton() {}
);
```

I have tried putting the token in a cookie (Which Tomcat9 is ignoring because of the format).  I'm looking into this issue separately at this time.

I have also tried making an XMLHttpRequest() for the welcome page which is getting me back the raw HTML, but am unsure if I need to reload the DOM somehow using this response...

**What is the best way to take the authorization token in the response, and put it in the header for the subsequent /GET for the /welcome page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added headers in the right way. To add the headers, you need to use `beforeSend()`:

```js
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWT);
},
```

This option need to be sent. Also, `JWT` here means the JWT, the token and `xhr` is the `XMLHttpRequest` raw object. This option should be sent to the `$.ajax()`'s parameter.

Comment: Does this get applied for all requests ajax and otherwise? if I configure the XMLHttpRequest object, Does the header still get applied when it attempts to call window.location? ?

Comment: @ItGrunt This will affect only the particular AJAX calling function where the parameter is passed to. For all request also you can do using [`.ajaxStart()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) method. My answer affects only the particular request we are talking about. Not everything else. If you use `window.location`, that's not an AJAX call, a normal GET request without any headers, so no.

Comment: Thanks for your response... so is it possible to use the xhr object to reload the entire page, scripts, css and all?  I have only seen it used in the past to load data from microservices into the DOM

Comment: @ItGrunt But in GET request normally it's definitely not possible to send authentication headers. But with JavaScript, yes, and with respect to Microservices, they use a special loading method, I am not sure about the name and I have also seen that way. But it's not possible in a normal GET request, and definitely not using `window.location`.